On ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and getting the popup: No updates and security fixes in 227 days
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
$

I'm getting the popup message:
Upgrade available
Ubuntu on 24.04.1 LTS.
This version will stop receiving updates and security fixes in 227 days

Is this a bug I was under the impression that the end date of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is 2027.
Regards,
Albert

Note: The popup seems to be activated by one of the last updates.

What's the output of apt policy base-files? For some reason it thinks you're on the first point release.

I am running ubuntu as a guest in a virtual machine

The ubuntu started as a gnome installation and kde was added later.

The output of apt policy base-files:
base-files:
Installed: 12ubuntu4.6
Candidate: 12ubuntu4.6
Version table:
*** 12ubuntu4.6 500
500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
12ubuntu4 500
500 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages

As I mentioned before, I have both ubuntu and plasma installed. I noticed that the message only pops up during a plasma session and not during an ubuntu session.
Is this a kubuntu issue?

It seems that the problem only occurs on installations that started as 20.04 and then were upgraded to 22.04.

The problem seems to be fixed.
The popup isn't displayed anymore.

More details needed. It could not have simply stopped. What have you done? Updates, installed some new software? Please add some details.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

What happened? How did you fix it?
